# Why do we say "Last modified" and not "Latest modified"?

Tags: date, user-interface, translation

Disclaimer: English is not my native language.
In school, I have always been taught that there is a difference in English between "last" and "latest".

"**Last**" to be used when there will be no other item afterwards, like "Mozart's last music piece".
"**Latest**" implying that there will be another item, like "Latest news" or "Latest updates".

But in user interfaces, I always see for modification dates "**Last** modified" and not "**Latest** modified". Why?

Do we not want to assume that there will be another modification? Or is it because the word is shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on english language / somewhere else (perhaps code review). Definitely not here.

Comment: Although I've voted to code this - here's a helper. I don't know the technical terms to explain it but "latest modified" would indicate it's the latest one in a group to be modified. Last modified shows when that specific one was *last* modified.